# log4j custom log level and properties file

Tags: log4j

I have the following custom logging level

```
public class SAMLLoggingLevel extends Level{

public static final String SAMLLOGGING_LEVEL = "SAMLLOGGING";
public static final Level SAML_EXCEPTION_LOGGING = new SAMLLoggingLevel(FATAL_INT + 1, SAMLLOGGING_LEVEL, 7);
public static final Level SAML_DEBUG_LOGGING = new SAMLLoggingLevel(DEBUG_INT+1, SAMLLOGGING_LEVEL, 7);
public static final Level SAML_ERROR_LOGGING = new SAMLLoggingLevel(ERROR_INT+1, SAMLLOGGING_LEVEL, 7);

protected SAMLLoggingLevel(int level, String levelStr, int syslogEquivalent) {
    super(level, levelStr, syslogEquivalent);
}
}
```

I try to log using the following

```
public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(xyz.class);

logger.log(SAMLLoggingLevel.SAML_DEBUG_LOGGING, "logger SAML_DEBUG_LOGGING");
logger.log(SAMLLoggingLevel.SAML_ERROR_LOGGING, "logger SAML_ERROR_LOGGING");
logger.log(SAMLLoggingLevel.SAML_EXCEPTION_LOGGING, "logger SAML_EXCEPTION_LOGGING");
```

my log4j.properteis file looks like this

```
log4j.logger.com.xyz=SAML_DEBUG_LOGGING, SAMLLoggingLevel
log4j.appender.SAMLLoggingLevel=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SAMLLoggingLevel.File=/SAML.log
log4j.appender.SAMLLoggingLevel.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SAMLLoggingLevel.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS zzz} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I get all the debub messages from all classes in com.xyz. I want to restrict only to the once that are logged using logger.log(SAMLLoggingLevel....)

Answer (score 2):

Change you code from

```
log4j.logger.com.xyz=SAML_DEBUG_LOGGING, SAMLLoggingLevel
```

to

```
log4j.logger.com.xyz=SAML_DEBUG_LOGGING#com.yourpackagename.SAMLLoggingLevel, SAMLLoggingLevel
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check out how to use Markdown formatting (there's a question mark next to the edit box; clicking on it provides the basics)